# Trouble enabling custom javascript on wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I tried adding custom scripts to my wordpress site, but it won’t activate javascript. The method i used is clearly working (as seen with the style.css file responding) , so the problem seems to be the javascript itself. Problem is, that same javascript is working just fine when i load up a live server in VSCode. Any ideas where the problem might be?

I enqueued both the stylesheet and the javascript files in functions.php. However, only the stylesheet is working. It tried using public scripts enqueue, as well as admin enqueues. None work

This is a snippet of 3 of my js functions that i’d like to apply to the page

```
///nav bar size response
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.navbar-nav').toggle();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sub-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
  })
  $(".other-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".other-menu").slideToggle();
  })
})

//button toggle
var menu = document.querySelector(".menu")
var menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn")
var closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close-btn")

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.add("active");
});

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.remove("active");
});

//header scroll

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  var header = this.document.querySelector("header");
  header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
});
```

I added them to the wordpress source js file as they are

*AN UPDATE, CLEARED ALL MY JS AND WROTE AN ALERT FUNCTION, AND IT WORKED!  SO NOW I KNOW THE PROBLEM IS MY CODE/ THE JS THAT I WROTE. I JUST DONT KNOW WHAT THAT PROBLEM IS EXACTLY. Like i said, it’s working just fine in VSCode…

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To troubleshoot this, put some console.log calls into your javascript, open the devtools in your browser and hit refresh. For us to help you we need to see at least a bit of your javascript code. Does it run before your page's `DOMContentLoaded` event fires?

Comment: @O.Jones     I’ve added a code snippet of my JavaScript. Kindly assist if you can?

Comment: You should put *all* your Javascript inside your `$(document).ready(function(){` . Why? If your code like `document.querySelector(".menu")` runs before the document is ready, it may not find the DOM (html) items you want it to find, because they are not yet loaded completely from the server. One of the joys of asynchronous programming!

Comment: i got it. my js was not firing after the html attributes had finished loading, like you mentioned about the DOMContentLoaded event. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Using all capitals is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude to do when you want help. Please edit the last paragraph to use normal casing.

Comment: My bad..that was not my intention